# USB 2.0 "This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

Tags: usb, microcontroller

This is probably a long shot question, but I try it anyway.

I'm developing hardware using PIC Microcontrollers (MicroChip). Communication is done through a FS USB 2.0 link.

I connect the microcontrollers to a Windows 10 Home edition, version 21H1, build 19043.1826. The processor is an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor.

First I used the PIC18F45K50, for which everything worked fine from day one. But due to the shortages on the market, I now am experimenting with PIC18F47J53. Both microcontrollers are working fine, as I can (for example) control a MAX7219 controlled display (3 x 7-segment) and also control a bunch of LED's using an STP08CP05TTR. Clock timings seem also ok - I measured it with an oscilloscope.

These 2 microcontrollers are pretty much the same, at least for the core functionality such as USB. The differences that are relevant for the issue I'm reporting here are:

- PIC18F45K50 uses internal clock of 8MHz, and has on board correction logic to keep clock synced for HS USB - this is a 5V processor
- PIC18F47J53 uses a XTAL of 16MHz, all should be within the USB 2.0 specs - this is a 3.3V processor

I'm using the MPLab X IDE v5.45 with the MCC (MPLab Code Configurator) in which I setup the System Module (to set the correct clock frequencies including the 48MHz for USB) and where I configure the USB.

In both microcontrollers, the setup of the USB is exactly the same. I even checked the 4 files that are automatically generated by MCC, and except for the descriptors (I used different names), all is exactly the same.

When I connect the USB to my PC (same port), then the PIC18F45K50 works perfect. But the PIC18F47J53 gives error code 10.

[image: The device cannot start. (Code 10)]

This does not happen every time. For example, if I try 10 times (connect/disconnect the cable), then I had it 7 times. 1 time the device even didn't appear, and 2 other times I read "The device is working properly.". Although, in the latter case, my software that communicates with my controller isn't working, so there is still something wrong.

Based on the above, the first I would think of is some hardware issue. Although, the strange thing is that things like vendor ID (0x4D8), Product ID (0xA), BCD Device Release (0x100), Serial Number (12345678), etc... seem always to be read out correctly. If there would be a hardware problem, shouldn't I have more random issues with this as well? Or is this data read out in a slower mode than Full Speed (because that could of course explain this)?

Below are screenshots via "Device Manager / Ports (COM & LPT) / my serial device", then selecting the property in the Details.

[image: Vendor and Product ID and Release]

[image: Serial number 1234567]

[image: Product String]

If I compare the properties from the working microcontroller (PIC18F45K50) with the not working one (PIC18F47J53), it looks like all are exactly the same.

I also tried to compare the D- (CH1) and D+ (CH2) signals between the 2 microcontrollers with my oscilloscope. My USB knowledge is not detailed enough to interpret the signals, but what I can tell is that both look exactly the same to me, both timing wise and voltage level wise. Be aware that the CH2 signal on the PIC18F47J53 (D+), the second screenshot, is clipping in the picture below, but I measured it later and it shows the same voltage level as for the PIC18F45K50.

[image: PIC18F45K50 D- and D+ signal]

[image: PIC18F47J53 D- and D+ signal]

Does anybody here a single clue where I should look at in the first place? The good news is that I have a working and not working version, so I can start debugging step by step and compare. But some hints as where to start would be appreciated.

EDIT 24JUL2022

I did the measurement with my oscilloscope again. Now I soldered 2 wires to the USB port to be able to easily attach my probes. This time, both D- and D+ signals have a Vpp of about 3.3V. I put some cursors which also shows a pulse-width of about 84ns, which correlates with the USB HS frequency of 12MHz (should be 83.33ns).

[image]

Comment: If the computer is retrieving the vendor ID and product ID but still showing an error then there is probably some bug in how your PIC handles one of the requests.  I would use the [Beagle USB 12](https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/) to take a look at exactly what packets are being exchanged.  There might be some free software analyzer that works too, but I haven't used those as much.

Comment: CH2: Vpp=36.8 / Vpp=9.80V. That's very strange. In the first case, it could be that your probe is not in 10x mode, while the DSO is. But the second case looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The reasoning that the vendor ID, product ID, etc... always come through correctly also made me think that the hardware is at least working correctly. Except if this data is being read at a lower speed, and afterwards USB switches to full speed, which then causes some trouble. But for what I could read in the USB specifications, there is no indication that this is the case, right? There could be something wrong with handling, but strangely enough, the SW is the same as for the working version. Spending 500 USD on a Beagle would be a very last option - this is for my hobby :-)

Comment: @Codo I checked my DSO and probes, and both are set to x10. But as I told, the second signal seems to have some clipping. I will redo the measurement. Is it correct that D-/GND is about 3.3V and D+/GND is about 37V? I know this is a differential signal, so not very sure how to measure it and interpret the results.

Comment: Both D+ and D- must be between 0V and 3.3V relative to GND. 37V is way off, but more likely a measurement problem than the real voltage.

Comment: @Codo I added an Edit in my question showing a new measurement with my DSO. Seems now that both D- and D+ signals are closer to what you expect. If I connect my DSO, then Windows seems not to detect the device in Device Manager, although I can measure some bursts (see new screenshot). If I disconnect my DSO, then the device shows in Device Manager, with the error 10 of course. It looks like there is some activity on the USB, but after a short while (1 second) it stops. Still not 100% sure if I'm dealing with a HW or SW problem. Will require much more investigation I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The Vusb on my PIC18F47J53 had a bad (or was even not) connected. I gave it another touch of my soldering iron, and bingo! Now the "error 10" has disappeared completely, and each time I connect/disconnect it gives "This device is working properly.", and error 10 never appears. I now also see a continues signal on my oscilloscope - not one that is disappearing after a while. And I could send/receive already some commands.

[image]